# Ignore unmounted file systems

Tags: nfs, disk-usage, devices, fstab

I've got two devices on my LAN: a Raspbian jessie and an Ubuntu 14.04. The latter has some **nfs** shared folders, which are available from Raspbian at startup, set up in its `/etc/fstab` file as:

```
192.168.1.10:/mnt/nfs/HDD /mnt  nfs     defaults,nofail,noatime          0       0
```

The problem is coming up when Ubuntu is offline and I try to run `df` on raspbian... infinite loop. No answer.

Does `df` have any way to ignore non-available devices? To show only those file systems that are currently available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automounter was designed exactly for this kind of problem. It automatically mounts drives (local or remote) only when they are needed, and unmounted them when they are no longer being used.

Install `autofs` on your NFS client and comment out (or remove) the entries in `/etc/fstab`. Edit `/etc/auto.master` and ensure that there is a line like this uncommented in the file

```
/net /etc/auto.net --timeout=120
```

Do not just uncomment the line `/net -hosts` as this requires NIS installed and configured to work - which is highly unlikely.

Restart the automounter with `service autofs restart`. You will now have access to your remote NFS filesystems under the `/net` directory. In your specific instance the path will be `/net/192.168.1.10/mnt/nfs/HDD`. You can then symlink that into your filesystem as if it were mounted:

```
ln -s /net/192.168.1.10/mnt/nfs/HDD /mnt/hdd
```

---

Some notes

1. My personal preference is to tweak the entries in `/etc/auto.master` so that items are managed underneath deeper less visible directories such as `/var/autofs/net` and `/var/autofs/misc` rather than `/net` and `/misc`, but for your specific situation I've left the configuration as standard as possible.
2. If you want to adjust the mount options for the NFS remote filesystem you will need to edit the file `/etc/auto.net` as options cannot be passed from `auto.master`.

Comment: Cheers! Finally I made it work: `-hosts` option wasn't able to see any nfs drives, so my `/etc/auto.master` file looks thus: `/net    /etc/auto.nfs` and `/etc/auto.nfs` thus: `hdd             192.168.1.10:/mnt/nfs/HDD`. I don't know why auto-discovering is not working though.

Comment: @HugorenMartinako the `-hosts` line should have used the executable `/etc/auto.net` to generate the entries on demand. You can try `/etc/auto.net 192.168.1.10` to see what it would have produced.

Comment: This is the output: `-fstype=nfs,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid \
 /mnt/nfs/HDD 192.168.1.10:/mnt/nfs/HDD`. Does it mean it's able to see it?

Comment: @HugorenMartinako answer updated to correct my misinformation about the `-hosts` entry.